# shiny app for a taking input of multiple fields

Tags: r, shiny

I `m trying to build an app like this:-

Choose: # this is selectInput (So only one can be chosen at a time) 
choice 1 
choice 2
choice 3
 once a choice is made then say choice 1 then the scree should display further sub option to that as,
In choice 1 select :
op1
op2
op3
op4

and these are multiple check box that is user can tick mark any number of checkboxs.
After this the relevant output is to be displayed.
and also I want the app to reflect the changes when the inputs are changed.

I have no clue to do this ,I`m trying this from few days but only managed to get the ui part done but nothing much on server.R code

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help you.

UI.R file

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

# input control for first choice

selectInput("first_choice", 
              label = h1("First Answer a General Question"),
              choices = list("select","A","B","C"),
            selected = "select"
              ),

#collapsable panel for second choice

h1("then get into details"),

bsCollapse(
bsCollapsePanel( title = "details",
                 uiOutput("second_choice")
                 ),
id = "collapser", multiple = FALSE, open = NULL
),
h2("first answer"),
h3(textOutput("first_answer")),
h2("second answer"),
h3(textOutput("second_answer"))

))
```

server.R file

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  #retrieve selected values and render text from selection

  output$first_answer  <- renderText({input$first_choice})
  output$second_answer <- renderText({input$dynamic})
  output$second_choice <- renderUI({

    switch(input$first_choice,
           "A" = checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", "Dynamic",
                                   choices = c("Aragon","Frodo"),
                                   selected = "option2"),
           "B" = checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", "Dynamic",
                                    choices = c("Bilbo","Gandalf","Sauron"),
                                    selected = "option2"),
           "C" = checkboxGroupInput("dynamic", "Dynamic",
                                    choices = c("Boromir","Legolas"),
                                    selected = "option2")

           )

  })

  #observe function in order to open the collapsable panel when the first answer is given


  observe({
    if (input$first_choice != "select") {
      updateCollapse(session,"collapser",open = c('details'))

      }
  })

})
```

this result in the following shiny app:

[image: shiny app dynamic answer showhing and change]

where the second menu opens only after the first get an answer and the options for the second question are dynamically changed based on the first answer.
selected answers are assigned to *first_answer* and *second_answer*.

Please note the use of shinyBS package for the collapsable panel.

You can find more on dynamic UI changes at the following Rstudio sources:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: thanks !,
actually the issue is with each first choice , the number of second choices varies. Here you have assigned 3 choices with each first choice but I wanted 4 choices with Percent White, 2 choices with Percent Black and so on..... Is it possible??!!

Comment: this should be what you were looking for. Please notice that the dynamic change is made possible by the renderUI() function and the switch() function. Find out more on those functions within the cited sources and the R documentation.